# The effect of changing system time during Service Pack deployment

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, update, service-pack, daylight-saving-time

I'm preparing to install SP1 on SharePoint 2013 environment next weekend. And there will be a switch to the daylight saving time on that weekend.
So I have this concern - what will happen if the system time will change while SP1 bits are installing or PSConfig.exe is running? Is it possible that there will be some bad consequences? 
It will not be easy to revert this update in case of trouble and it will be a real pain to reschedule it after such failure.

Can anyone share such experience?

Comment: can't you schedule to do the update so it finishes before/starts after the time change?

Comment: @RafaelBonametti This would be very hard due to organizational specifics. Rescheduling is our least wanted option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've got the [answer](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d1af9466-fefe-4e02-960c-877c0b2bf17f/the-effect-of-changing-system-time-during-service-pack-deployment?forum=sharepointadmin) on MS Technet Community:

Most time is tracked and translated via UTC and not local time. So as long as the TZ isn't changing, you should be alright.